# How to get the id after fetch call?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, body-parser

I want to target the id by gettng it but I seem to only get the whole data which if I console log it I see id and such but I have no clue how to only print the id in console log
Here is an example code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/get/' + f)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
```

Comment: If the data is in JSON format, then `data.id` should work.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I tried that, it returns undefined but if I console.log data it shows me Object { data: (1) […] } -> data: Array [ {…} ] -> 0: Object { id: 92, aktivitet: "5", forening: "5", … }

Comment: Try data[0].id, then according to the log you specified this should work, else post a picture of the log in the question.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor gives me data[0] is undefined. I will show you the log. This is with data[0] https://gyazo.com/bb6c32da834d355583de409cb853a90e and this is with only data https://gyazo.com/95f7cfad3699a26cd4127de0fbbea831

Comment: Try this data.data[0].id?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor lol that worked, confusing since it returns object, data, etc but specify to go data then data and then id is confusing to me but hey it worked, thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` object has this structure:

```
data = {
    data: [{
      id: some value,
      // some other key-value pairs
    }],
    // some other key-value pairs
}
```

The `data` is a JSON object with a key also named `data`. This key refers to an array, which stores JSON objects which contains `id`.

The answer is `data.data[0].id`.

That's why its confusing.

Comment: Thanks my guy :)